# How to encrypt postgresql database with Django as the backend?

Tags: django, postgresql, security

I am using Postgresql database with Django rest framework, I want to encrypt my database to improve security but I didn't find any documentations which clearly explains the encryption process and algorithms underlying it.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: [postgres encryption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/encryption-options.html) . [full disk encryption in ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/uc20/full-disk-encryption) .  [ssl encryption on nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

it belongs to way you want to use data,you can encrypt your data with django(in views or models with python encryption features and algorithms) and save it to data base or you can use for example pgcrypto([github repo](https://github.com/incuna/django-pgcrypto-fields)
it encrypt data in database level.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).